# How to increase brightness of camera in Android

Tags: android, camera, brightness

How do I change the brightness level of the camera?

Comment: do you have solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the camera parameters as pointed out by @appleskin, would either of these methods help?  [setWhiteBalance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setWhiteBalance%28java.lang.String%29) or [setExposureCompensation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29)

Comment: thank for your kind response steve, but both the function are not available in api level 7

Comment: ah, do you specifically need the brightness to be at the point of taking the photo?  Or can you post-process the image to brighten it as soon as it is taken?  It just might be a limitation you can't work around without upgrading the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your camera [parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try parameters.set("iso", 400); or whatever int value is supported on your device

Answer (score -1):

used following way to increase or decrease brightness ( its for activity so you can used anywhere for camera or activity also), its working fine.so it helping to anyone.

call following function in your activity :

```
    private void setSeekbar() {

    seekBar.setMax(255);
    float curBrightnessValue = 0;
    try {
        curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
                getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int screen_brightness = (int) curBrightnessValue;
    seekBar.setProgress(screen_brightness);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Nothing handled here
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Nothing handled here
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // Set the minimal brightness level
            // if seek bar is 20 or any value below
            screenBrightness(progress);
            editor.putInt("brightness",progress);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
  }
```

method of screenBrightness :

```
 private void screenBrightness(double newBrightnessValue) {
    /*
     * WindowManager.LayoutParams settings = getWindow().getAttributes();
     * settings.screenBrightness = newBrightnessValue;
     * getWindow().setAttributes(settings);
     */
          WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
          float newBrightness = (float) newBrightnessValue;
          lp.screenBrightness = newBrightness / (float) 255;
          getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
 }
```

following method call before **SeekBarChangeListener** :

```
  void changeBrightnessMode() {

    try {
        int brightnessMode = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
        if (brightnessMode == Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC) {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something useful

    }
}
```

Comment: the code you posted let you adjust brightness of Android System not cameraPreview brightness

Comment: We want increase brightness of custom camera(Preview) not screen brightness. if you done that please share.

Comment: This is not the brightness of camera. it is normal Brightness